# Two subplots in Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create two subplots in Python (using Anaconda 2.7) but code which I wrote generates two graphs, both not showing too much.
Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 23)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 23)

df = web.DataReader("BAC", "yahoo", start, end)

df['100MA'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Adj Close'], 100, min_periods=1)
df['STD'] = pd.rolling_std(df['Close'], 25, min_periods=1)

print(df.tail())

ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
df[['Adj Close', '100MA']].plot()
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)
df['STD'].plot()
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2000, 10, 23)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 23)

df = web.DataReader("BAC", "yahoo", start, end)

df['100MA'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Adj Close'], 100, min_periods=1)
df['STD'] = pd.rolling_std(df['Close'], 25, min_periods=1)

print(df.tail())
f,axarr = plt.subplots(2,1)
df[['Adj Close', '100MA']].plot(ax=axarr[0])
df['STD'].plot(ax=axarr[1])
plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @StanislavJirák no problem, If the answer addresses your question accept it by clicking on the checkmark of that answer ([like here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)) so that others notice it will work in the first look.

Comment: I was waiting until I can accept the aswer due to the time limit (5m).

Comment: I think it's better to switch to `pandas_datareader` module as `pandas.io.data` is deprecated and doesn't work with Pandas 0.19.0. So use `import pandas_datareader.data as web` instead of `import pandas.io.data as web`. PS +1 for the great answer